# Inner Join Invalid Object Name

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Trying to do a simple inner join query but keep getting errors

```
Select Alias from Db.SchmaName.Customers as Customer
Select Alias from Db.SchmaName.Orders as Order
Inner Join Order on Customer.Alias = Order.Alias
```

The Db and SchmaNames are both exactly the same but Alias column is different between the 2 tables.

Both of the select statements work as expected but the error for the Inner Join is

> "Invalid object name 'Order'"

I get this error even if I do not use the table alias and instead type out the full path to the table

Comment: Those are *two* queries, not one.

Comment: I said this in my answer, however, I'm impressed that's the error you're getting. `ORDER` is a **reserved** word in SQL Server. You should not be using reserved (or even keywords, really) as names for objects; it generally just causes headaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm surprised that's the error you're getting. `ORDER` is a reserved word in SQL Server, don't use it for your object and alias names, you should be getting the error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'order'.

Don't use reserved words (or even key words really) for object names, or if you have to, quote them (`[Order]`). Personally I would do:

```
SELECT Alias --This is missing an alias as well, so would be ambigous
FROM Db.SchmaName.Orders O
     INNER JOIN Customer C ON C.Alias = O.Alias;
```

Aliases are great for making your SQL succinct. Aliasing the table `Customers` as `Customer`, doesn't really do that. A lot of people (like myself), tend to use a few characters to alias a table. So, for `Customer` I used `C`. Personally, I tend to use the letters of specific words in the object's name. For example, if I have a table called `StockItem` I would probably use `SI`. For a table I have called `ic_BD_HPT1` I use `HPT1`.

Comment: Awesome that works perfectly, thanks for the advice on aliasing tables as well will certainly be using that as good practice in the future!

Comment: @JoshuaDavidson you're welcome. if the answer solved the problem, then please do mark it as the solution; this'll help others should they have the same problem,

Answer (score 1):

use different table alias name rather `key word of SQL(Order)`,another issue Alias column is exist in your both table so use table.column in selection and
your join need like below

```
Select Customer.Alias from Db.SchmaName.Customers as Customer
inner join Db.SchmaName.Orders as O
 on Customer.Alias = O.Alias
```

Answer (score 1):

Those are *two* queries, not one.

```
Select Alias from Db.SchmaName.Customers as Customer
Select Alias from Db.SchmaName.Orders as Order
Inner Join Order on Customer.Alias = Order.Alias
```

Is actually

```
Select Alias from Db.SchmaName.Customers as Customer;

Select Alias from Db.SchmaName.Orders as Order
Inner Join Order on Customer.Alias = Order.Alias;
```

The second query is invalid, as it tries to join the `Order` alias to itself.

To join two tables you need to specify the tables themselves in the FROM, JOIN statements. If you want to select a column that exists in both tables you have to explicitly specify which one you want, eg:

```
Select Order.Alias 
from Db.SchmaName.Orders as [Order]
Inner Join Db.SchmaName.Customers as Customer 
    on Customer.Alias = [Order].Alias;
```

`ORDER` is a keyword which means you need to either enclose it in square brackets or use a better alias. In fact, `Orders` is just fine :

```
Select Orders.Alias 
from Db.SchmaName.Orders 
Inner Join Db.SchmaName.Customers as Customer 
    on Customer.Alias = Orders.Alias;
```

Answer (score 0):

Order is a Keyword in SQL. You can not use Keywords in SQL for aliases, except if you put [] around the alias.
I would use a different name for the alias.

Answer (score 0):

There are two queries in your question.

This is one

```
Select Alias from Db.SchmaName.Customers as Customer
```

And this is the second one

```
Select Alias from Db.SchmaName.Orders as Order
Inner Join Order on Customer.Alias = Order.Alias
```

The error you are getting is on the second query,
You are trying to `JOIN` against the `Alias` you've given to the table `Orders`, i.e `ORDER`. What you should do instead is reference the Alias on the `ON` clause, like so

```
Select Order.Alias, Customer.Alias
from Db.SchmaName.Orders as Order
INNER JOIN Db.SchmaName.Customers as Customer on Order.Alias = Customer.Alias
```